# CSRF Security Error wildfly 8.2.0

Tags: java, spring-security, csrf, wildfly-8, dwr

I am making use of `DWR 2.0` and `Spring 3.2.5` in my web application. 
And the application is deployed in `wildfly 8.2.0` with `HA mode` which 
will make use of `standalone-ha.xml`. When I run the application in 
normal configuration I am not getting any king of security error. 
But in `HA`(High Availability mode I am getting `CSRF Security Error`
popup. I have gone through different blogs. For example
http://blog.2partsmagic.com/2010/11/resolving-dwr-csrf-security-error-popups/

They are saying 
      `<Context useHttpOnly=”false”>` 
in tomcat context.xml file.
  How can I do that in wildfly 8.2.0. and Where?
   Thanks in advance...!

Answer (score 1):

Add the following tag under  `<servlet-container>` tag of standalone-ha.xml

```
<session-cookie http-only="false" secure="false"/>
```

It will resolve your issue.